# Append data to Access Table with ADO using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to append Excel data to an Access table using Excel VBA.

I have data in a worksheet in Excel (active worksheet). I would like to append the contents of the row A4-BL4 to a Table in Access called Table1.

I am trying to do this with ADO and a recordset.

My code gives me an error

> Arguments of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another

on the line:

```
 rs.Open qry, cn, adOpenKeyset
```

I am new to working with Access.

*It is crucial this be triggered from Excel not Access*

```vb
Sub EXPORT()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

    strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\Users\yilmadu001\Desktop\Database.accdb;"
 
    cn.Open (strcon)

    qry = "SELECT * FROM Table1"
    rs.Open qry, cn, adOpenKeyset

    rs.AddNew
    rs.Fields("Date") = Range("A4").Value
    rs.Fields("Order Number") = Range("B4").Value
    rs.Fields("Product Code") = Range("C4").Value
    rs.Fields("E-Number") = Range("D4").Value
    rs.Fields("size") = Range("E4").Value
    rs.Fields("type") = Range("F4").Value
    rs.Fields("type2") = Range("G4").Value

    rs.Fields("Voltage") = Range("H4").Value
    rs.Fields("Compound") = Range("I4").Value
    rs.Fields("Number") = Range("J4").Value
    rs.Fields("Tag Number") = Range("K4").Value
    rs.Fields("Quantity") = Range("L4").Value
    rs.Fields("zero") = Range("M4").Value
    rs.Fields("net") = Range("N4").Value

    rs.Fields("Actual net") = Range("O4").Value
    rs.Fields("min") = Range("P4").Value
    rs.Fields("Actual min") = Range("Q4").Value
    rs.Fields("max1") = Range("R4").Value
    rs.Fields("max2") = Range("S4").Value
    rs.Fields("Top") = Range("T4").Value
    rs.Fields("2") = Range("U4").Value

    rs.Fields("side") = Range("V4").Value
    rs.Fields("5") = Range("W4").Value
    rs.Fields("Bottom") = Range("X4").Value
    rs.Fields("8") = Range("Y4").Value
    rs.Fields("side2") = Range("Z4").Value
    rs.Fields("10") = Range("AA4").Value
    rs.Fields("set1") = Range("AB4").Value

    rs.Fields("set2") = Range("AC4").Value
    rs.Fields("set3") = Range("AD4").Value
    rs.Fields("Usage1") = Range("AE4").Value
    rs.Fields("Usage2") = Range("AF4").Value
    rs.Fields("Main (%)") = Range("AG4").Value
    rs.Fields("A (%)") = Range("AH4").Value
    rs.Fields("ratio (%)") = Range("AI4").Value

    rs.Fields("set3") = Range("AJ4").Value
    rs.Fields("set4") = Range("AK4").Value
    rs.Fields("Core ") = Range("AL4").Value
    rs.Fields("Tip1") = Range("AM4").Value
    rs.Fields("Tip2") = Range("AN4").Value
    rs.Fields("Tip3") = Range("AO4").Value
    rs.Fields("set5") = Range("AP4").Value

    rs.Fields("speed") = Range("AQ4").Value
    rs.Fields("speed2") = Range("AR4").Value
    rs.Fields("speed3") = Range("AS4").Value
    rs.Fields("speed4") = Range("AT4").Value
    rs.Fields("speed5") = Range("AU4").Value
    rs.Fields("speed6") = Range("AV4").Value
    rs.Fields("speed7") = Range("AW4").Value

    rs.Fields("setting") = Range("AX4").Value
    rs.Fields("Selected") = Range("AY4").Value
    rs.Fields("S/U1") = Range("AZ4").Value
    rs.Fields("S/U2") = Range("BA4").Value
    rs.Fields("S/U3") = Range("BB4").Value

    rs.Fields("ON/OFF") = Range("BC4").Value
    rs.Fields("YES/NO") = Range("BD4").Value
    rs.Fields("NOTES") = Range("BE4").Value
    rs.Fields("Size1") = Range("BF4").Value
    rs.Fields("Size2") = Range("BG4").Value
    rs.Fields("Size3") = Range("BH4").Value
    rs.Fields("Temp1") = Range("BI4").Value

    rs.Fields("Temp2") = Range("BJ4").Value
    rs.Fields("Temp3") = Range("BK4").Value
    rs.Fields("Temp4") = Range("BL4").Value

    rs.Update

    rs.Close
    db.Close

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: @HansUp now I am getting a new error on the line "rs.AddNew" and it says current recordset does not support updating. This may be a limitation of the provider, or of the selected locktype.

Comment: @HansUp none of those worked unfortunately, still error "current recordset does not support updating. This may be a limitation of the provider, or of the selected locktype"

Comment: `rs.Open "Table1", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockPessimistic`

Comment: @HansUp that seems to have fixed it, but now it is giving me an error "Invalid SQL statement expected "Delete", "Insert", "Procedure", 
"Select", or "Update" " on the same line, I think I am missing another argument

Comment: See Ibo's answer.  Sorry I don't use ADO; this is easier with DAO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify your recordset to be update-able:

```
rs.Open qry, cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

since your query is simply getting all of the records you can use `adCmdTable` option, but you have to pass the name of the table only:

```
rs.Open "Table1", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
```

Comment: Synthax error FROM clause in the line rs.Open qry, cn, adOpenKeyset,adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

Comment: try without adCmdTable

Comment: Do you have Table1 in your ACCESS database? try to close everything because if you are in design mode etc your connection/queries will fail

Comment: If you use `adCmdTable`, you need to only pass the table name, not an SQL query, that's what's causing this error

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth yes that was the problem, thank you for your comment!

Comment: also use an explicit referencing for the range, for example use `rs("field1").value=WS.range("A1")` where `WS` is a worksheet object (`set WS=Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`)